# c pointers equivalent login in javascript

Tags: javascript, c, node.js

I am trying to convert this `c` function to a `javascript` class:

```
for(i=0; i<inputLen; i++)
{
    //Calculate the constants
    pucSeqX = m_pucSeqX;
    pucSeqM = m_pucSeqM;
    for(j=0; j<m_iRounds; j++)
    {
        *(pucSeqX++) = arc4_getRandom();
        *(pucSeqM++) = arc4_getRandom();
    }
    //The last m_iRounds-1 rounds
    ucPlain = rostrIn[i];
    pucSeqX = m_pucSeqX + m_iRounds1;
    pucSeqM = m_pucSeqM + m_iRounds1;
    for(j=m_iRounds-1; j>0; j--,pucSeqX--,pucSeqM--)
    {
        if(*pucSeqM <= ucPlain)
            ucPlain -= *pucSeqM;
        else
        {
            ucPlain += ~*pucSeqM;
            ucPlain++;
        }
        ucPlain ^= *pucSeqX;
    }
```

This is my try:

```
  for(i = 0; i < buf.length; i++)
  {
    pucSeqX = m_pucSeqX
    pucSeqM = m_pucSeqM

    for(j = 0; j < m_iRounds; j++)
    {
      pucSeqX[j] = this.getRandom()
      pucSeqM[j] = this.getRandom()
    }

    console.log(pucSeqX)
    console.log(pucSeqM)

    ucPlain = buf[i]
    pucSeqX = m_pucSeqX + m_iRounds1
    pucSeqM = m_pucSeqM + m_iRounds1

    for (j = m_iRounds-1; j > 0; j--, pucSeqX--, pucSeqM--)
    {
      if (pucSeqM <= ucPlain)
        ucPlain -= pucSeqM
      else {
        ucPlain += ~pucSeqM
        ucPlain++
      }

      ucPlain ^= pucSeqX
    }
```

But it doesn't seem to generate the same results. Is there something I am missing?

I'm confused with the pointers on the C code and how they would be in javascript.

Comment: There is no concept of pointers in JavaScript. It would help us help you if you showed the rest of the program, and what it is expected to do.

Comment: @Chirag64 can be found @ [runnable](http://runnable.com/U6UMtLquqboTG0P8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only have very basic knowledge of Javascript, so I'll only give you C-code equivalents to your code you can transform more easily.

Here

```
pucSeqX = m_pucSeqX + m_iRounds1;
pucSeqM = m_pucSeqM + m_iRounds1;
```

`m_pucSeqX` is a pointer value (maybe a decayed array), and the statements are equivalent to

```
pucSeqX = &m_pucSeqX[m_iRounds1];
pucSeqM = &m_pucSeqM[m_iRounds1];
```

In the follow `for` loop you are decrementing the pointers `pucSeqX` and `pucSeqM`, which at the beginning of the loop point to the `m_iRounds1`-indexed elements of `m_pucSeqX` and `m_pucSeqM`, respectively, so you could decrement the indexes and access the array:

```
pucSeqX_ind = m_iRounds1;
pucSeqM_ind = m_iRounds1;

for (j = m_iRounds-1; j > 0; j--, pucSeqX_ind--, pucSeqM_ind--)
{
    if (m_pucSeqM[pucSeqM_ind] <= ucPlain)
        ucPlain -= m_pucSeqM[pucSeqM_ind];
    else {
        ucPlain += ~m_pucSeqM[pucSeqM_ind];
        ucPlain++;
    }

    ucPlain ^= m_pucSeqX[pucSeqX_ind];
}
```

HTH

Comment: I'm checking it out. will give you feedback.

Comment: Still doesn't give me the same values as the C code. Would you try to look at the whole C and JS file?

Comment: @majidarif: This C code doesn't give the same result as the original C code? Or do you mean, your transcription of this to JS doesn't? How long is your whole file?

Comment: I believe my transcriptions isn't spot on. It is pretty short. 50 lines of code.

Comment: @majidarif: Yes, 50 LOC are OK.

Comment: What are `m_pucSeqX` and `m_pucSeqM`? They're global in the C file. Are they used in a different translation unit?

Comment: Sorry, you lost me. That is all there is to the files. I'm not too good with c.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56029/discussion-between-mafso-and-majidarif).

Comment: I have to ask you said the JS file I posted on paste bin isn't updated to your code, I checked and it is. Did I follow the code you gave wrongly?

Comment: @majidarif; sry, my bad. I mixed up my browser tabs and actually read your upper link I had still open.